# Migrating AppFuse application from Tomcat 7 to Jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jboss, migration, appfuse

I am very new with Java Web Servers and Web Applications.
We had a very old Appfuse framework based application running fine on Tomcat 5.
Appfuse is a sprint based frame work with hubernet and few others things build into it.

I need to transfer it to JBOSS EAP 6.1. 
Initially I am testing on standalone mode

Thinks I have already done
1. jboss-web.xml created 
2. oracle database module created and database connection added in standalone.xml
3. demo application installed to test logging and authentication system.

but the application is not working.
I have no clue what is not working because I can not debug this thing any more.

To start with my login page is not working 
For login we had Form based authentication. It use to go to a servlet page and use to check few things like database and LDAP and finally use to update database and use to redirect the page as j_security_check?j_username=user&j_password=09d841bf7ab817bf248133610fc2c13b346690aa&j_uri=

What i did to check is I created a login-module with DatabaseServerLoginModule and validating from database also have created a demo app to check if this is working and it is all good in demo app.

Even If I disable my login servlet and login filter and use the simple login jsp page created for demo app I can login and do few things before I breaks again.

Error I am getting is as below

16:17:12,170 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) PBOX000263: Executing query select password from users where ad_username=? with username pealison
16:17:12,173 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) PBOX000283: Bad password for username pealison
16:17:12,173 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) PBOX000244: Begin abort method
16:17:12,173 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:284) [picketbox-4.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:408) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:216) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:280) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:373) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:389) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <display-name>Login Filter</display-name>
  <filter-class>com.mas.etcs.webapp.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>enabled</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/logout.jsp</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
  <display-name>Login Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-class>com.mas.etcs.webapp.action.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>authURL</param-name>
   <param-value>j_security_check</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>isSecure</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>encrypt-password</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>algorithm</param-name>
   <param-value>SHA</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

I am looking at this thing for more than a week now and I am going mad need help.

Comment: My first mistake was SHA algorithm. My servlets were working fine and my old login servlet use to  take the user name and password from the web form and after some checking finally it use to do another redirection to j_security with usernaem and SHA hex password. As a result the server security module was already getting the password with sha encription and then it was doing another encription of that password and then was checking with the database as a result the password was always false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of my problems solved after I put oracle module in ee subsystem.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
    <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false
    </spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
    <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true
    </jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
    <global-modules>
        <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc" slot="main" />
    </global-modules>
</subsystem>
```

Still fighting with system.out.